# Heroku certs -- Didn't include CA bundle and now cannot update (Pem can't be blank, is invalid, expires at can't be blank)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, heroku, https, ssl-certificate

I have the COMODO Extended Validation offered by NameCheap.com. It gives me these files:

```
[domain]_com.crt
AddTrustExternalCARoot.crt
COMODOAddTrustServerCA.crt
COMODOExtendedValidationSecureServerCA.crt
```

I did everything I was supposed to in regards to unpacking site.key and what not, but what I did not do was combine the 4 items listed above in to one file. I merely did

```
$ heroku certs:add [domain]_com.crt site.key --app myapp
```

After doing some research and cat'ing them all in to one file

```
$ cat [domain]_com.crt COMODOExtendedValidationSecureServerCA.crt /
  COMODOAddTrustServerCA.crt AddTrustExternalCARoot.crt > [domain]_com-bundle.pem
```

I am trying to do

```
$ heroku certs:update [new_file].pem site.key --app myapp
```

But I get these errors:

```
Resolving trust chain... done
Updating SSL Endpoint [app].herokussl.com for [myapp]... failed
 !    Pem can't be blank
 !    Pem is invalid
 !    Expires at can't be blank
```

Did I do the PEM file wrong? Did I `cat` them in the wrong order?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think I figured it out and made a blog post about it here:
http://starvingdeveloper.wordpress.com/2012/09/18/comodo-ev-ssl-with-heroku-if-you-did-it-wrong-the-first-time/

Comment: Also, this is NOT advertising. I had such an interesting time with it, being an SSL noob, that I decided to create a little weblog because of this and this is the first post. Hopefully this will help someone in the future